# JQuery issue with IE7

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i've this piece of javascript calling a Fancybox function.
I set the trigger click because I want to automatically open the fancybox when page loads.
In every browser it's ok, except for IE 7 (compatibility mode).

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $("a#hidden_link").fancybox({
        'speedIn'       :   10, 
        'speedOut'      :   30, 
        'showCloseButton' : true,       
}).trigger('click');
```

IE7 shots this error: "Identificator, string or number is expected" on the last line when the .trigger('click') is called..

I can't figure out..thx

Answer (score 5):

Extra comma on the second to last line. This is a somewhat nasty one as other browsers tend to be more lenient about it; the standard however doesn't allow an extra comma at the end of an object literal.

Comment: Thanks Matti, unfortunately I didn't undestand well what you wrote.      Must I add an extra comma? where ? thank a lot

Comment: Ok, i solved it. I found some extra commas IE7 doesn't like and it works fine for whole now. You saved me Matti, thanks so much